# How can I enable xdebug coverage mode in (laradock) workspace？

Tags: docker, docker-compose, laradock

I'm trying to run `composer test`, the tests seems working well, but after tests done, I got a warning below.

```bash
Tests:  236 passed
Time:   6.77s

WARN  Unable to get coverage using Xdebug. Did you set Xdebug's coverage mode?
```

I've tried set `WORKSPACE_INSTALL_XDEBUG=true` in my laradock `.env`, also add `xdebug.mode=coverage` line to my `xdebug.ini` file in the workspace folder.

After done these, I ran `docker compose build workspace` and recreated the workspace container, but still got the same warning and can't saw the coverage shows.

I can't find any info on laradock document, how can I supposed to enable the coverage mode correctly?

---

This is my `xdebug.ini` under workspace folder.

```ini
; NOTE: The actual debug.so extention is NOT SET HERE but rather (/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini)

xdebug.mode=coverage
xdebug.remote_host="host.docker.internal"
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM

xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_enable=0
xdebug.cli_color=0
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="~/xdebug/phpstorm/tmp/profiling"

xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req

xdebug.var_display_max_children=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_data=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=-1
```

Comment: check php-fpm directory, it might also have a debug.ini. you don't know for sure that debugging goes through the workspace container. Make a info.php file and put `xdebug_info();`, do you see coverage enabled? xdebug.mode can be multiple. Example: `xdebug.mode=debug,coverage`

Comment: @UnderDog Yes, there does have one in php-fpm folder, but I'm not debug with web, isn't the php-fpm working with the nginx sock？What's the relation about php-fpm in workspace bash in my case？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've traced the execution of each line in workspace dockerfile, there's a replace line at [here](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/blob/master/workspace/Dockerfile#L376) which replace my `xdebug.ini` to final like below：

```ini
; NOTE: The actual debug.so extention is NOT SET HERE but rather (/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini)

xdebug.mode=coverage,debug  # My settings here.
xdebug.client_host="host.docker.internal"
xdebug.discover_client_host=false
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM

xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.mode=debug  # This line overwrite my setting.
xdebug.cli_color=1
; xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.output_dir="~/xdebug/phpstorm/tmp/profiling"

xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
; xdebug.remote_mode=req

xdebug.var_display_max_children=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_data=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=-1
```

The replace line overwrite my `xdebug.mode` so the coverage mode is not enabled, I quick fixed by change the line position to below：

```ini
; NOTE: The actual debug.so extention is NOT SET HERE but rather (/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini)

xdebug.remote_host="host.docker.internal"
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM

xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_enable=0
xdebug.cli_color=0
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="~/xdebug/phpstorm/tmp/profiling"

xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req

xdebug.var_display_max_children=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_data=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=-1

xdebug.mode=coverage,debug  // Move setting to below
```

---

### Update

Conclusion by traced the command of workspace dockerfile, there is no official optional can setting the xdebug coverage mode, but you can work around by modify the `xdebig.ini` in workspace folder.

Just notice that your `xdebug.mode` line must be after the line `xdebug.remote_enable=0` or it will be overwrite by default.

In my case, I'm testing the composer packages which by `composer test`, if you are testing with `php artisan test` and need coverage mode, you'll need to modify the `xdebug.ini` in php-fpm folder.

Comment: You've answered your own question, which is awesome. In a few days you can mark your answer as the best answer ;-)